# Can't open SAFs OPEN_DODUMENT dialog on one android 8 device

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

How can this be? From android 5 onwards, this should always work, shouldn't it?

**Exception**

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE flg=0x43 (has extras) }
```

This occurs on an *HTC U12+* running android 8.

**Code**

```
public static void selectFolder(Activity activity, int requestCode, boolean localOnly)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, localOnly);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

Comment: That would appear to be a bug on that device, as there is no good reason for a phone to fail to have that activity. Note, though, that some specialized Android environments may lack these activities, such as Android TV. You might consider getting rid of the three `addFlags()` calls, though, as none of them are valid for this situation.

Comment: @CommonsWare Does that mean, that SAF isn't covered by CTS?

Comment: @user1643723: I don't really know. Bear in mind, though, that AFAIK the CTS is only "officially" applied for new hardware. So, whatever version of Android originally shipped on the HTC U12+ would have been tested. Anything after that, from security patches to OS upgrades to other HTC firmware changes, does not get tested by Google AFAIK. So, it's possible this problem crept in after CTS testing. Or, it's possible that CTS does not check to see whether there is an activity for each of the SAF `Intent` structures.